# MKPinAnnotationView versus MKAnnotationView

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mkpinannotationview

I've inherited a project which throws this warning

```
Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'MKPinAnnotationView *' from 'MKAnnotationView *'
```

at this line

```
pinView=[[[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID]autorelease];
    }
```

I'd like to return the project without warnings so I'm hoping someone here has a quick answer

Full code:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation: (id  <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 

    NSUserDefaults *prefs=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 

    {

        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";

        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView  dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];


        if (!pinView) {
            pinView=[[[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID]autorelease];
        }

    }   
    pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
    [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    [mapView.userLocation setSubtitle:[prefs objectForKey:@"CurrentLocationName"]];
    return pinView;        
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pinView` variable is declared as an `MKPinAnnotationView` but that line creates an `MKAnnotationView`.

Change this line:

```
pinView=[[[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation...
```

to:

```
pinView=[[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation...
```

You should also have an `else` part to that `if` to handle annotation view re-use:

```
else
    pinView.annotation = annotation;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are dequeing the pin annotation view and along with that you are allocating the annotation view as your pinview which was technically wrong!!! That's why it was firing the warning I guess. Try this may solve your issue.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation: (id  <MKAnnotation>)annotation {


pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView  dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];


if (!pinView) {
        pinView=[[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID]autorelease];
    }

..........
..........

}
```